# Why does my Spring Security login.jsp puke CSS and how do I fix it?

Tags: css, jsp, spring-security

I have created a custom login page for a legacy java web app using Spring Security and a JSP page.  The legacy app does NOT use Spring MVC.  I preview it in MyEclipse and it applies my CSS styles.  But when I run it in debug mode and look at it with Firefox it has problems.  1) The CSS is not rendered.  2) After submitting the form, it gets redirected to the CSS file, so the browser shows the text of the CSS file!

I've been over this for a couple of days, and haven't found a solution on this site or any other.  I've never had to use JSP or Spring Security before, so I'm not even sure of the culprit.  Can anyone point out where I'm screwing up?

My **login.jsp** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:url value="/user_pass_login" var="loginUrl"/>
<html>

<HEAD>
    <link href="Tracker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <TITLE>ATP3 Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>
    <DIV id="login_body"
            align="center" >
        <h1>Sample Tracker Login</h1>

        <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
            <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    Failed to login.
                    <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
                                <BR /><BR />Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
                    </c:if>
                </div>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                <div class="alert alert-success">You have been logged out.</div>
            </c:if>
            <BR />
            <label for="username">Username:</label> 
            <input 
                type="text" 
                id="username"
                name="username" />
            <BR />
            <BR />
            <label for="password">Password:  </label> 
            <input
                type="password"
                id="password" 
                name="password" />
            <BR />
            <BR />
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input 
                    id="submit" 
                    class="btn" 
                    name="submit" 
                    type="submit"
                    value="Login" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </DIV>
    </body>
</html>
```

After logging in I get redirected to the url for my CSS file, **Tracker.css**:

```
/** Add css rules here for your application. */


/** Example rules used by the template application (remove for your app) */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000555;
  margin: 40px 0px 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

#login_body, #formLogin {
    color: #000555;
    background-color: #F6FCED;  
}

.sendButton {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

/** Most GWT widgets already have a style name defined */
.gwt-DialogBox {
  width: 400px;
}

...
```

After thinking about what @Santosh Joshi said, I reviewed the security settings within my Spring Security configuration XML file.  And here is what was happening:

1. When the **login.jsp** first loads it doesn't have access to the **Tracker.css** file, because the security settings prevent it (see below for the corrected file), so the page isn't formatted.
2. When the user successfully logs in, the CSS file is found, but since the JSP is malformed, it just spews the CSS file.

**The Fix**

1. I modified the **login.jsp** as follows:

   1. Remove line 1 with xml definition
   2. Move line 4 with a url variable declaration to just above the form tag
   3. Add an html document type definition just below the JSP directives
2. I added a permission line to the Spring Security XML http tag

The new **login.jsp** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>

    <HEAD>
        <link href="Tracker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <TITLE>ATP3 Login</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>
        <DIV id="login_body"
                align="center" >
            <h1>Sample Tracker Login</h1>

            <c:url value="/user_pass_login" var="loginUrl"/>
            <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
                <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                        Failed to login.
                        <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
                                    <BR /><BR />Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
                        </c:if>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">You have been logged out.</div>
                </c:if>
                <BR />
                <label for="username">Username:</label> 
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    id="username"
                    name="username" />
                <BR />
                <BR />
                <label for="password">Password:  </label> 
                <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password" 
                    name="password" />
                <BR />
                <BR />
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <input 
                        id="submit" 
                        class="btn" 
                        name="submit" 
                        type="submit"
                        value="Login" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </DIV>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a snippet from the security XML file.  Note the new intercept-url tag for **Tracker.css**:

```
<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
<http auto-config="true" 
        use-expressions="true" 
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/"
        access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*"
        access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*/*"
        access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico"
        access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/Tracker.css"
        access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_WRITE','ROLE_READ')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
        login-processing-url="/user_pass_login"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
</http>
```

Comment: All my HTML code was good, so the only change I needed to make to fix this same problem that I was having was to add a line to permitAll traffic to the css folder. Once I let the traffic through, it seemed to fix the problem... really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a problem with the path of the CSS, where have you placed the CSS

`<link href="Tracker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

you can also debug your application in Firefox using firebug, if it's not applying then it means that CSS has not downloaded properly just check console in Firefox for 404 or other errors. Also cheek where is Firefox actually wants to get this( the URLFirefox is referring) CSS .

Comment: Well, when it pukes up the CSS it is finding it.  I put both the CSS and the JSP in the root folder, so it's not hidden by WEB-INF.  I will double-check to see if permissions are set correctly in Spring Security to be able for the link to work...

Comment: I'll give you credit for this because you got me on the right track, but everyone please see the corrected solution above.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same problem with font awesome. After login I would see css contents. I noticed font-awesome folder is outside of css folder, so I added a new security rule:

```
.antMatchers("/font-awesome/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
```

I was using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf and Spring Security.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file location is already a clue, if you've already added permitAll() to you spring security config file, make sure that the css file (or image file in my case) is actually accessible via url, ie it might need to be in the resource folder.

In my case my image file was hidden in a WEB-INF folder, which is not exposed directly when you are just logging in or just by accessing via url, which somehow breaks spring security.