# Spring security login crashes after the login page it shows the css , js, image files . How to fix this?

Tags: spring

when i open the web application from browser.

localhost:8080/myapp

it shows the login page with out styled in the css file. even refresh also it shows normal form but we can give the login credentials to log into the application. 
now the problem is it shows the js files i used in the my application

localhost:8080/myapp/some.js

now we remove the some.js file and hit the url now it shows the css file or js file. it happens in two to three times after re hit the url it shows the correct login form and goes to the dashbord.

how to fix this issue please help me out this problem.

security.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <security:form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/default"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" ></security:form-login>
      <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <security:user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

login.jsp file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/anchor.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet">

    <div>
    <form name='loginForm' class="form col-md-12 center-block"
        action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

        <div id="loginModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
                        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                            <div class="error">${error}</div>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
                        </c:if>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name='username' 
                           class="form-control input-lg"
                                placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name='password'
                                               placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <button>Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
                        <!-- </form> -->
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

please help me out this issue. all most myapp is finished the all modules now this time to deliver to customer, kindly please help me out this issue.
How to fix this when i login it redirects to the css or js or images resources files.

This is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml       
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Kindly please help me out this issue

i suffred same problem like this

[Why does my Spring Security login.jsp puke CSS and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895039/why-does-my-spring-security-login-jsp-puke-css-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your security mapping at this line:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

your resources are also secured by spring.
You may try to move your resources in a js (, css...) folder and add this to your configuration:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none" />
```

(could not test this. no spring security project near me ;) )

edit:
just got a note that this is old spring security ( < 3.1 ) syntax and deprecated.
Use multiple http tags instead if you are using spring security >= 3.1 (but your code looks like old config)

```
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
```

from: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-form-and-basic